# How do you properly write a function that takes a parameter by reference in C?

Tags: c, pointers, reference

I am searching this information for a while now. Searching around the internet, many sites says that a Function reference, is written like this:

```
//Example 1
#include <stdio.h>

void somma (int a, int b, int *c) {
    *c = a + b;
}

int main (void) {
    int a = 4;
    int b = 2;
    int c = 8;

    somma(a, b, &c);

    printf("Risultato somma: %d", c);

    return 0;
}
```

But this, is what I have learnt at school:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void somma(int a, int b, int &c) {
    c = a + b;
}

int main(void)
{
    int a = 4;
    int b = 2;
    int c = 8;

    somma(a, b, c);

    printf("Risultato somma: %d", c);

    return 0;
}
```

This actually confuses me, because if I try to compile a program (written like I learned at school), I get a compilation error, which involves the function itself:

```
[ripasso2.c 2019-08-25 21:19:47.684]
ripasso2.c:3:30: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before '&' token
 void somma(int a, int b, int &c) {
                              ^

[ripasso2.c 2019-08-25 21:19:47.684]
ripasso2.c: In function 'main':
ripasso2.c:13:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'somma' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     somma(a, b, c);
     ^~~~~
```

What am I doing wrong? Did I have a mix up with the pointer?

Comment: Neither of these is a "function reference". One is an argument of pointer type, the other is not valid c.

Comment: I think you are mixing C++ references with C pointers in your formal parameter list. As @EOF said, no function reference seen in you code.

Comment: @U.Windl yes, i actually mixed up C++ with C. Usually at school we compile program in C, but in this particular case we had to compile the program with the command "c++ -o program program.c" instead of "cc -o program program.c"

Comment: Note that references are basically syntactic sugar for pointers, allowing a slightly less messy syntax.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This:

```
void somma(int a, int b, int &c) {
```

is **not** valid C syntax. It's C++ syntax. If they taught you this in school as C, then it's wrong.

The compiler produces an error about this and then also warns you about the fact that the function `somma` is not declared, because it could not be correctly processed. It's really just one error.

The valid C declaration is the first one:

```
void somma (int a, int b, int *c) {
```

---

If you want to compile the C++ version (the one using `int &c`), then you must **use `g++`**, not `gcc`. You can install it with a simple `sudo apt install g++` (assuming you are on Linux), and then you can compile the program just like you do with `gcc`.

Comment: Thank you so, so much! You made me remeber that in this particular case, we compiled the program in C++, via command "c++ -o program program.c". C and C++ are so similar...